# How to update a table with composite keys using Massive ORM?

Tags: massive

Using Rob Conery's Massive micro-ORM; is it possible to work with tables that have composite keys?

I can't quite see how to assign more than a single column name as 'PrimaryKeyField'. Anyone managed to do so? More specifically; How do i do an Update() when the primary key consists of two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this comment on GitHub; https://github.com/robconery/massive/pull/50 - with the following comment from Rob;

> (...) I've had this discussion with others (using SubSonic) with
>   respect to composite keys and to be honest - that's more code than I'd
>   like to use to support what I consider an edge case (and not a
>   terribly good database design outside of many to many joins)

So it seems that composite keys will not be supported. And I can totally see the reasoning behind it. Luckily we're in control over the database, so I believe we can go around it by adding a surrogate key, and let the current composite key become an unique index instead.